# Python/java framework for developing artificial intelligence for board games like Diplomacy/Risk

Tags: ai, game-theory

I am trying to pick a python/java framework for developing artificial intelligence for board games like Diplomacy/Risk for research purpose. I am specifically looking for multiplayer, multiple-round games without any dominant strategies that require players to cooperate as well as non-cooperate at certain times.

The idea of the research is to not build the game itself or the AI bot, but to discover novel methods for game theory, specifically to deceive other players- bots or humans.

This research is specifically based on Deceptive Artificial Intelligence. Please share any frameworks(game code with stubs for decision making) that you may know about. It would be a lot of help for my work.

If you have any ideas about some other game that I can pick, please mention that as well.

I have tried a few frameworks but the lack of documentation is extremely annoying and I haven't been able to move forward in the process.

Thanks and Regards!

Comment: Welcome to the site, Uttakarsh. Unfortunately, we don't accept list type questions on this site. If you have specific technical questions to ask, we're happy to answer those.

Comment: Hi @Engineer! I am sorry for posting an irrelevant question here. The reason why I posted an answer to this question here is that I have tried posting it on multiple stack-exchanges and I was unable to get an answer. Unfortunately, this question is considered irrelevant everywhere. Kindly review the policy regarding this type of questions. Otherwise please comment on this question again and I will remove this

Comment: Yes, the reason this type of question is considered off-topic here is the same reason it's considered off-topic on other StackExchange sites: our Q&A format is not the best way to get high-quality, objective, up to date answers about what tech users should use. It risks fossilizing out-of-date information, or opinion that's suitable for one project/team but unsuitable for others using the site as a resource. For these reasons, non-Q&A format venues like GameDev.net's formums, [chat], or gamedev social media will tend to get you better answers & discussion on topics like this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After trying out a few frameworks, I decided to go with PyRisk.
The code can be found here: https://github.com/chronitis/pyrisk

Thanks and Regards
Uttakarsh Tikku